# I18n in qml side doesn't work

Tags: qt, qml

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QTranslator ruLang;
if (ruLang.load(":/Application_ru"))
 qDebug() << "we're good..............";
app.installTranslator(&ruLang);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

return app.exec();
```

It seems like .qm translation file loads well but qml side of application doesn't changes at all.

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't work in QML? How did you test it? Does it work in C++ part? Did you translate QML files with `lupdate`? Please provide all suitable code.

Comment: @folibis thanks man, already solved myself, sorry for troubling